# Detecting Value of Generic Custom Attribute Without Adding Code Directly to Element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out, using Javascript, how to detect the value of an email input by using the last attribute "aria-invalid" (will equal "true" or "false"). The issue is other fields on the page use the same attribute "aria-invalid" in the same fashion. Not sure how I can read the value of the email input attribute only? I can NOT add any code to the element and NO jQuery please.

```
<input class="masked-zip-code not-empty input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Enter a valid (5-digit) ZIP code." data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" data-val-required="Enter a ZIP code" id="ZipCode" name="ZipCode" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ZipCode-error" aria-invalid="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a way to tell which one is which, and since `aria-invalid` is shared, it can't be used for this. You can use an ID or `type="email"` to distinguish such field. See the following:

```
<input class="masked-zip-code not-empty input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Enter a valid (5-digit) ZIP code." data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" data-val-required="Enter a ZIP code" id="ZipCode" name="ZipCode" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ZipCode-error" aria-invalid="true">
<input class="masked-zip-code not-empty input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Enter a valid (5-digit) ZIP code." data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" data-val-required="Enter a ZIP code" id="ZipCode" name="ZipCode" type="email" value="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ZipCode-error" aria-invalid="true">
```

You can then use this code to access `aria-invalid` value:

```
var aria-invalid-value = document.querySelector("input[type='email']")[0].getAttribute('aria-invalid');
```

Comment: The question specifically stated no jQuery.

Comment: @bbailes Updated without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
var invalid = document.getElementById('ZipCode').getAttribute('aria-invalid');
console.log(invalid);
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxb4kj7x/2/)